# How to add "required" attribute to mvc razor viewmodel text input editor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, data-annotations, html-helper

I have the following MVC 5 Razor HTML helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShortName, 
  new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "short name"})
```

I need this field to be required (i.e. have a red outline when user navigates out without putting a value inn). In a WebForms HTML 5 I could just say `<input type="text" required />` to have this effect.
What is the proper syntax to accomplish this in a Razor syntax?

Comment: Protip: The `@` on `@placeholder` is not needed. It's only needed when the name is a keyword like `class`.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

You can use the `required` html attribute if you want:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShortName, 
new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "short name", required="required"})
```

or you can use the [RequiredAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.requiredattribute.aspx) class in .Net. With jQuery the `RequiredAttribute` can Validate on the front end and server side.  If you want to go the MVC route, I'd suggest reading [Data annotations MVC3 Required attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142947/data-annotations-mvc3-required-attribute).

OR

You can get really advanced:

```
@{
  // if you aren't using UnobtrusiveValidation, don't pass anything to this constructor
  var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>(
    Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix));

 attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
 attributes.Add("placeholder", "short name");

  if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType
      .GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true)
      .Select(a => a as RequiredAttribute)
      .Any(a => a != null))
  {
   attributes.Add("required", "required");
  }

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShortName, attributes)

}
```

or if you need it for multiple editor templates:

```
public static class ViewPageExtensions
{
  public static IDictionary<string, object> GetAttributes(this WebViewPage instance)
  {
    // if you aren't using UnobtrusiveValidation, don't pass anything to this constructor
    var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>(
      instance.Html.GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes(
         instance.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix));

    if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.ContainerType
      .GetProperty(ViewData.ModelMetadata.PropertyName)
      .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RequiredAttribute), true)
      .Select(a => a as RequiredAttribute)
      .Any(a => a != null))
    {
      attributes.Add("required", "required");
    }
  }
}
```

then in your templates:

```
@{
  // if you aren't using UnobtrusiveValidation, don't pass anything to this constructor
  var attributes = this.GetAttributes();

  attributes.Add("class", "form-control");
  attributes.Add("placeholder", "short name");

  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShortName, attributes)

}
```

Update 1 (for [Tomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281014/tomas) who is unfamilar with ViewData).

[What's the difference between ViewData and ViewBag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705426/whats-the-difference-between-viewdata-and-viewbag)

Excerpt:

> So basically it (ViewBag) replaces magic strings:
>
> ```
> ViewData["Foo"]
> ```
>
> with magic properties:
>
> ```
> ViewBag.Foo
> ```

Comment: O', its really nice 1 !

Comment: how can we show custom message with required html attribute?

Comment: @AashishKumar using the *Ask Question* button in the upper right to ask a new question.

Comment: @ErikPhilips I already asked the question regarding the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485898/how-to-add-custom-error-message-with-required-htmlattribute-to-mvc-5-razor-vie

Comment: Really effective answer.

Comment: This answer is some kind of mess, the static helper which is posted here would not work!. The is no class ViewWebPage, but WebViewPage. Also what is ViewData? The ViewData is not refering and it is not global class in MVC. No way this code would work.

Comment: @Tomas a simple *I think you misspelled WebViewPage as ViewWebPage* would suffice.  [System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage | Properties | ViewData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.webviewpage.viewdata?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_WebViewPage_ViewData).  With 61 up-votes (so far) others have figured it out, it's really not to hard.

Comment: @Erik, that I want to say that not I but you misspelled ViewWebPage class name and after you have corrected the class name your extension method still wouldn't work. I didn't try to run it but ViewData would be not found in that extension method scope. You didn't tested your code either :)

Comment: really good and clear way to set properties to the html controls

Answer (score 21):

On your model class decorate that property with `[Required]` attribute. I.e.:

```
[Required]
public string ShortName {get; set;}
```

Comment: Sadly, this adds `data-val-required` to the element, not `required` like you'd expect it to.

Comment: @humanoidanalog - The expected result would actually be `data-val-required`, you are working in MVC.

Comment: As a web developer I expect required attributes to make my forms validate as "required" under html5. Not as required under a couple MB's of jquery libraries.

Comment: I think this should be the right answer working in MVC. Upvoting for more exposure.

Comment: [Required] works as expected as long as you are using jqueryValidate and unobtrusive. It wont work right out of the box.

Answer (score 13):

A newer way to do this in .NET Core is with `TagHelpers`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro

Building on these examples ([MaxLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43477621/maxlength-annotation-to-maxlength-input-property), [Label](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42907712/111978)), you can extend the existing `TagHelper` to suit your needs.

### RequiredTagHelper.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProjectName.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "asp-for")]
    public class RequiredTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        public override int Order
        {
            get { return int.MaxValue; }
        }

        [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            base.Process(context, output); 

            if (context.AllAttributes["required"] == null)
            {
                var isRequired = For.ModelExplorer.Metadata.ValidatorMetadata.Any(a => a is RequiredAttribute);
                if (isRequired)
                {
                    var requiredAttribute = new TagHelperAttribute("required");
                    output.Attributes.Add(requiredAttribute);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'll then need to add it to be used in your views:

### _ViewImports.cshtml

```
@using ProjectName
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper "*, ProjectName"
```

Given the following model:

### Foo.cs

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjectName.Models
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Full Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and view (snippet):

### New.cshtml

```
<label asp-for="Name"></label>
<input asp-for="Name"/>
```

Will result in this HTML:

```
<label for="Name">Full Name</label>
<input required type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Full Name field is required." id="Name" name="Name" value=""/>
```

I hope this is helpful to anyone with same question but using .NET Core.

Comment: Your entire method body could simply be replaced with `return validatorMetadata.Any(vm => vm is RequiredAttribute)`

Comment: @ErikPhilips you are correct, and for the sake of simplicity I have updated my answer. However, it should be noted that there are potential performance concerns when using LINQ. Particularly when used in rendering the view. YMMV

Comment: Nice. I feel like they should build this in as part of ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 3):

I needed the "required" HTML5 atribute, so I did something like this:

```
<%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @required = true })%>
```

Comment: required="true" is incorrect and the input will not be evaluated as required.

Comment: Indeed, it was without double quotes. I edited the code.

Answer (score 1):

@Erik's answer didn't fly for me.

Following did:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShortName,  new { data_val_required = "You need me" })
```

plus doing this manually under field I had to add error message container

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.ShortName, null, new { @class = "field-validation-error", data_valmsg_for = "ShortName" })
```

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Inline razor expressions do not end with a semicolon (;) (statements in razor a code block do), so there shouldn't be a semicolon at the end of the razor expression.  (Tried to simply edit the line of code but Adam Michalik, for some, reason rejected the edit). See http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-c

Comment: should be @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ShortName,  new { data_val_required = "You need me" }) without the semicolon.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.