# How to add custom error message with “required” htmlattribute to mvc 5 razor view text input editor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am naive to Asp.Net MVC.

I have a partial view(ASP.Net MVC) in which I have some required fields I want to show custom error message if any of the required field in not provided. Below is the complete cshtml code for my partial view.

```
@model CMSAdminPanel.ViewModel.ProductView
<h4>Material And Labour Cost For Each Size</h4>
<hr />
@Html.ValidationSummary(false, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.ServiceView.ListPriceView.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].ProductSizeType)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].ProductSizeTypeName, "Size - " + Model.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].ProductSizeTypeName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].MaterialCost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].MaterialCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].MaterialCost, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].Profit, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].Profit, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].Profit, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I want to show custom message "Material cost is required" while I am getting "This field is required". So I want to override this difault error message on client side.

I want to achieve something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", **data_val_required = "LabourCost is requried"**} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any suggestion/solution would be great help

Comment: did you try to use the data annotation on the MaterialCost in your model? add the Required attribute from data annotations and pass the message in the error message parameter

Comment: @NoorSamara Yes, firstly I was trying data annotation on my model for required attribute and as well as for message also but for partial view model annotation is not working. So i try htmAttribute "required" and it's working fine however it show error message "this field is required".

Comment: I did a test myself and the custom Required message works fine, using this property: `public decimal MaterialCost {..}{..}`, both when triggered from a View *and* from a Partial View. This was with MVC v5.2.3. Are you using that too, or perhaps an older version?

Comment: @PeterB Yes its working fine for both the cases but I want to do client side validation not using "ModelState.IsValid" and required attribute in model.

Comment: Please check the below link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53042131/how-to-override-default-required-error-message/58543227#58543227

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I find out a way to override this default required message on Client Side by using htmlAttribute **title** property and below is the code :

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required", title = "LabourCost is requried"} })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost,"", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: somehow this only works on textinputs for me, if I have an `EditorFor` `type="date"` or `type="number"` it gives it's default error message

Answer (score 55):

In your model class, add change the [Required] attribute to

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Material cost is required")]
public decimal MaterialCost {get;set;}
```

Another approach is to set it from JavaScript using JQuery or override the attribute that sets it. by default the output of the `ValidationMessageFor` is

```
data-val-required="The field is required.".
```

SO, you can override this value in your markup

Comment: could you please tell me how can we override default output of ValidationMessageFor to "Material cost is required". Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can override that in your model class which is used in the view, just put the line i put in my answer.

Comment: This is a partial view so I just want to do client side validation not "ModelState.IsValid" in my Controller.

Comment: The Html Helper creates a client side validation as well as the server side one

Comment: Is there any other way if i don't want to use required attribute in my model?

Comment: Then use the other way I explained in my answer by putting `the data-val-required="The field is required.".`

Comment: I tried this 

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ServiceView.ListPriceView[i].LabourCost, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control",data_valmsg_replace=true,data_val_required = "Labour Cost Field required", required = "required" } })

 but still I am getting "This field is required". :(

Answer (score 5):

in your model

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Material cost is required")]
public doubleMaterialCost { get; set; }
```

and you can choose to load it from Resources and pass resource string if you have multiple cultures in your site.

or in your Action

```
public ActionResult(YourModel model)
{
    if (model.doubleMaterialCost == 0)
            ModelState.AddModelError("doubleMaterialCost ", "Material cost is required");
```

Comment: I used this annotation in my model already but in case of partial view this in not working.

Comment: @AashishKumar Can you share your controller action.

Comment: @AashishKumar Also I edit my answer with another way of validation, you can also try this way.

Comment: Actually I want to do something at client side not on controller level. Is it possible?